# Is this correct? "Enjoy life with people who makes you forget social networks"

Tags: grammaticality

Is this correct? My friend says it is, but I am not sure.

[image: Enjoy life with people who makes you forget social networks]

I'm not a native speaker; is this grammatically correct?

Comment: @wyatt The sentence on the t-shirt; *"Enjoy life with people who makes you forget social networks"*

Comment: Yes, the sentence written on the shirt in the picture. Thanks @eirikdaude =)

Comment: Can we say *forget something* instead of *forget about something*?

Answer (score 2):

Almost right.

> Enjoy life with people who **make** you forget social networks

People is plural, and you only use **makes** with singular, for example

> Enjoy life with someone who **makes** you forget social networks

Comment: I wonder if the mistake was intentional, perhaps for humorous effect?

Comment: @J.R. If you had travelled in South East Asia, you would not even consider that possibility.

Comment: @Javababe And what does it have with the south of Asia ?

Comment: @cardinal, T-shirts with english writing are very fashionable: many are ungrammatical or use inappropriate words. For example, filipinos and koreans do not differentiate the pronunciation of the letters F and P: so people think that a T shirt saying "poxy lady" is a compliment to the wearer.